# Python inserting list of integers into CSV column after other data

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to insert a new column into a CSV file after existing data. For example, my CSV file currently contains:

```
   Heading 1     Heading 2
   1 
   1
   0
   2
   1
   0
```

I have a list of integers in format:

```
 [1,0,1,2,1,2,1,1]
```

**How can i insert this list into the CSV file under 'Header 2'?**

So far all i have been able to achieve is adding the new list of integers underneath the current data, for example:

```
   Heading 1     Heading 2
   1 
   1
   0
   2
   1
   0
   1
   0
   1
   2
   1
   2
   1
   1
```

Using the code:

```
 #Open CSV file
 with open('C:\Data.csv','wb') as g:
            #New writer
    gw = csv.writer(g)
            #Add headings
    gw.writerow(["Heading 1","Heading 2"])
            #Write First list of data to heading 1 (orgList)
    gw.writerows([orgList[item]] for item in column)
            #For each value in new integer list, add row to CSV
    for val in newList:
        gw.writerow([val])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code that correct the bug:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest


# Creating a CSV file
with open(r'Data.csv','wb') as f:
    fw = csv.writer(f)
    fw.writerows( (('Heading 1', 'Heading 2'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('0'),
                   ('2'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('0'))   )


print "The CSV file at start, read by a csv.reader :\n"
with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    fr = csv.reader(f)
    print '\n'.join(map(repr,fr))


print '\n------------------------------------------'
newdata = [10,0,10,20,10,20,10,10]

with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    fr = csv.reader(f)
    newrows = [fr.next()]
    newrows += (a+[b] for a,b in izip_longest(fr, newdata,
                                              fillvalue=[0]))

print 'newrows\n',newrows

with open(r'Data.csv', 'wb') as f:
     csv.writer(f).writerows(newrows)
print '------------------------------------------\n'


print "The new CSV file created, read by a csv.reader :\n"
with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    fr = csv.reader(f)
    print '\n'.join(map(repr,fr))
```

It displays:

```
The CSV file at start, read by a csv.reader :

['Heading 1', 'Heading 2']
['1']
['1']
['0']
['2']
['1']
['0']

------------------------------------------
newrows
[['Heading 1', 'Heading 2'], ['1', 10], ['1', 0], ['0', 10], ['2', 20], ['1', 10], ['0', 20], [0, 10], [0, 10]]
------------------------------------------

The new CSV file created, read by a csv.reader :

['Heading 1', 'Heading 2']
['1', '10']
['1', '0']
['0', '10']
['2', '20']
['1', '10']
['0', '20']
['0', '10']
['0', '10']
```

## EDIT

Even more condensed

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest
from os import remove,rename

# Creating a CSV file
with open(r'Data.csv','wb') as f:
    fw = csv.writer(f)
    fw.writerows( (('Heading 1', 'Heading 2'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('0'),
                   ('2'),
                   ('1'),
                   ('0'))   )

print "The CSV file at start, read by a csv.reader :\n"
with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    print '\n'.join(map(repr,csv.reader(f)))


#------------------------------------------
newdata = [10,0,10,20,10,20,10,10]

with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f, open(r'newData.csv','wb') as g:
    fr = csv.reader(f)
    gw = csv.writer(g)
    gw.writerow(fr.next())
    gw.writerows( a+[b] for a,b in izip_longest(fr, newdata,
                                                fillvalue=[0]) )
remove (r'Data.csv')
rename (r'newData.csv',r'Data.csv')

#------------------------------------------

print "The new CSV file created, read by a csv.reader :\n"
with open(r'Data.csv','rb') as f:
    print '\n'.join(map(repr,csv.reader(f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

some_ints = [1,0,1,2,1,2,1,1]

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    cols = izip_longest(csvin, some_ints, fillvalue='')
    csvout.writerows(cols)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got two related issues:

- Writing to the same file that you're reading
- Emitting just the new data instead of a new row that includes both the new and old data.

Start by reading the data into memory:

```
with open(r'C:\Data.csv','rb') as f:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Then transform the list of tuples into a new list of tuples with the new data:

```
newdata = [1,0,1,2,1,2,1,1]
newrows = [rows[0]]            # keep the current two headers
newrows += izip_longest(rows[1:], newdata, fillvalue=0)
```

Lastly, write the data back out to disk:

```
with open(r'C:\Data.csv', 'wb') as f:
     csv.writer(f).writerows(newrows)
```

Comment: This worked. Although it placed the items in CSV column 1 into brackets e.g. Header 1(row 1)= ['1'] Header 2(row 1)= 1